# placing sliding drawer on top of another layout

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

i want to show my left to right sliding drawer on top of another layout..
how do i do that??

the blue portion is the sliding drawer...it is not getting placed on top of the other layout..
i have used this [link](http://samplecodez.com/android/slidingdrawer.php#) for creating sliding drawer.
Pls help! thanx in advance!

and here is my code

```
    `      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:background="#325462">


         <Button    
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativelayout"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Application Form"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dashboardbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboardimg"
            android:onClick="dashboardpage" />

            </RelativeLayout>  
                          <com.android.lthomepage.Transparent
            android:id="@+id/popup_window"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="30px">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/changepass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change Online Password" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/changpin"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change Offlin Pin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logout" />

    </com.android.lthomepage.Transparent>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="13.08"
            android:background="@drawable/hdpi1" >
          <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="388dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/displayDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Select Application Date" 
            android:textSize="10dp" />

            <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/pickDate"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/displayDate"
           android:src="@drawable/calendaricon" />



            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rpfno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/displayDate"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="RPF Application no." >

           <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dear Sir/s," />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I/We am/are requesting you to extend the finance facility to me/us for" />

            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/finance_rupees"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/finance_rupees"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/finance_rupees"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Rs." />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="for a tenure of" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tenure"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                android:ems="10" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text=" months as per applicable rate of interest for purchase of new / used assests" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/asset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:ems="10" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/asset"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/asset"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/asset"
                android:text=" from your company, kindly consider my/our application. " />
                <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:text="Exit"
               android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
       android:id="@+id/info"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
       android:background="@drawable/i_info" />

        <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_saveandcontinue"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_exit"
       android:text="Continue"
       android:textSize="18sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

              <RelativeLayout
                 android:layout_width="50dp"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView1"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1" >

                  <Button
            android:id="@+id/pf1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/applicant" />

                <Button
            android:id="@+id/pf2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pf1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pf1"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/refer" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/pf3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pf2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pf2"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:background="@drawable/asset" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/pf4"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pf3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pf3"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/office" />

             </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **[Sephiroth](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/)**'s sliding drawer. Which provide attributes for direction like,

```
<attr name="direction">
    <enum name="rightToLeft" value="0" />
    <enum name="bottomToTop" value="1" />
    <enum name="leftToRight" value="2" />
    <enum name="topToBottom" value="3" />
</attr>
```

So just pass in your layout that which type of direction you want and thats it.

```
<it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    my:direction="topToBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    my:handle="@+id/handle"
    my:content="@+id/content">
    <include
        android:id="@id/content"
        layout="@layout/pen_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
</it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
```

Try this, will definitely helps you.

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayout is designed for overlapping views.

To overlap the whole layout do

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              .....
         >       

          <RelativeLayout .... 
           >
                    all your staff goes here
          </RelativeLayout>

          <SeekBar     .... />

  </FrameLayout>
```

To overlap a "sub-layout", wrap this layout with  FrameLayout and place SeekBar after it (but inside FrameLayout).